# PHP Subtotal from array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach

Can someone please explain how to obtain the total of the values coming under each of the two outer array elements?  I want to end with an array showing the values for each date Nov 18, 2011 and Nov 22, 2011.  Here is the array data:

```
Array
(
[Nov 18, 2011] => Array
    (
        [C] => Array
            (
                [T] => 49783.531672
                [X] => 25013.184
            )
        [S] => Array
            (
                [T] => 32908.863528
            )
        [I] => Array
            (
                [T] => 44561.52
            )
    )
[Nov 22, 2011] => Array
    (
        [C] => Array
            (
                [T] => -5168.944696
            )
        [S] => Array
            (
                [T] => -3823.890504
            )
    )
)
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Could you give an example of your desired output? It's not clear if you want only one sum per date or multiple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A script would be:

```
$results = array();
foreach($array as $element){
    $sum = 0;
    foreach($element as $subelement){
        foreach($subelement as $item => $value){
            $sum = $sum + $value;
        }
    }
    array_push($results, $sum);
}
```

This would give you an array of the sums.  You could of course name each if you so desired and so on.

**Edit: Got ahead of myself. Edited to me sum, not count**

Comment: Thanks @3321thec but I don't want to count, but to sum.

Answer (score 4):

If you want one sum per date:

```
$totals = array();
foreach ($origarray as $date => $inner) {
    $totals[$date] = array_sum(array_map('array_sum', $inner));
}
```

If you want multiple sums per date:

```
$totals = array();
foreach ($origarray as $date => $item) {
    foreach ($item as $innerk => $innerv) {
        $totals[$date][$innerk] = array_sum($innerv);
    }
}
```

Comment: For PHP 5.3+: `$totals = array_map(function ($i) { return array_sum(array_map('array_sum', $i)); }, $array);` :)

Comment: These worked great too!  Thanks.  I especially like the one-liner.  Great work @deceze and Francis.